# How to find integer array size in java

Tags: java, arrays, printing, size, range

below is my code which is throwing error:

```
Cannot invoke size() on the array type int[]
```

Code:

```
public class Example{
int[] array={1,99,10000,84849,111,212,314,21,442,455,244,554,22,22,211};    
public void Printrange(){

for (int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
    if(array[i]>100 && array[i]<500)
{
System.out.println("numbers with in range ":+array[i]); 
}


}
```

Even i tried with  `array.length()` it also throwing the same error. When i used the same with `string_name.length()` is working fine.

Why it is not working for an integer array?

Comment: Arrays does not have a size() method. They have a length field. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: was this question necessary?..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The length of an array is available as

```
int l = array.length;
```

The size of a `List` is availabe as

```
int s = list.size();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused between size() and length.

(1) The reason why size has a parentheses is because list's class is List and it is a class type. So List class can have method size().

(2) Array's type is int[], and it is a primitive type. So we can only use length

Answer (score 1):

Integer Array doesn't contain size() or length() method. Try the below code, it'll work. ArrayList contains size() method. String contains length(). Since you have used int array[], so it will be array.length

```
public class Example {

    int array[] = {1, 99, 10000, 84849, 111, 212, 314, 21, 442, 455, 244, 554, 22, 22, 211};

    public void Printrange() {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            if (array[i] > 100 && array[i] < 500) {
                System.out.println("numbers with in range" + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `array.length` is what you want!

Answer (score 0):

There is no method call `size()` with `array`. you can use `array.length`

Answer (score 0):

Array's has

```
array.length
```

whereas List has

```
list.size()
```

Replace `array.size()` to `array.length`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {

    int[] array = { 1, 99, 10000, 84849, 111, 212, 314, 21, 442, 455, 244, 554,
            22, 22, 211 };

    public void Printrange() {

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // <-- use array.length 
            if (array[i] > 100 && array[i] < 500) {
                System.out.println("numbers with in range :" + array[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can find length of array by using  array_name.length attribute

int [] i = i.length;